# Ubuntu grep on Windows does not find all entries

Tags: regex, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, string-parsing

I've exported a bunch of MS-Outlook mails to a text file. Now I'm trying to find some particular lines within that text file, but this seems not to work:

```
Prompt>/C/Temp_Folder$ egrep "Found crash|process disappearance " testtttt.txt | wc -l
13
Prompt>/C/Temp_Folder$ grep "Found crash" testtttt.txt | wc -l
11
Prompt>/C/Temp_Folder$ grep "process disappearance " testtttt.txt | wc -l
3
```

Opening this file in Notepad++, I have these results:

```
Found crash : 921 matches
process disappearance : 4975 matches
```

This can be interesting:
When I launch the `grep` without the `wc -l`, I see following result at the end:

```
Binary file testtttt.txt matches
```

This probably means that the file is treated as a binary file, although it's just a "regular" textfile.

When I ask what kind of file I'm dealing with, I get following result:

```
file testtttt.txt
testtttt.txt: news or mail, ISO-8859 text, with very long lines, with CRLF line terminators
```

What's going on here: is it the `news or mail`, the `ISO-8859`, the `very long lines`, ..., and how can I solve this?

For your understanding, I'm working on a Linux subsystem on a Windows-10 machine (the Ubuntu app from `Canonical Group Limited`).

Comment: The cause maybe `CRLF`.Try to convert them to LF with `sed`. Also check the file permissions, gid, uid etc.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: I already did a `dos2unix` and backwards but this did not solve the issue.

Comment: @Biswapriyo: about gid, uid (I believe you mean `user ID` and `group ID`): the file permissions are ok: if there would be any issues with those, the file would not be readable at all, while here it's just partially readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue using the Notepad++ feature `Find all in current document`.